# Regex to fetch patterns excluding file extensions

Tags: c#, regex

I've a pattern as mentioned below:

```
MS-<Digits>
```

If digits have a prefix `MS-`, I need to fetch the whole word.

Example:

> This is just an illustration of regex having a word MS-1234, MS-1234b, MS-123 and MS-12345. There is a file uploaded with name MS-12.jpg

From the above paragraph, regex should return following words only

- MS-1234
- MS-123
- MS-12345

If word is followed by `comma ,` `any white-space` or `full stop .` then it should be matched by regex but **the word should not be matched if it is followed by a file extension or similar pattern e.g. MS-123.jpg**

I've tried it with following regex:

```regex
MS-(\d)*(\.|\,)\s
```

Comment: Please check this regex: [`(MS-\d+)(?=,|\s|$|\.(?:\s|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/hW4qA5/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
MS-[0-9]+(?=[.,]\s|\s)
```

or

```
MS-\d+(?=[.,]\s|\s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there just use a positive lookahead.

```
@"MS-\d+(?=[.,]?\s)"
```

or

```
@"MS-\d+(?=[.,]?(?:\s|$))"
```

or

```
@"(?<=^|\s)MS-\d+(?=[.,]?(?:\s|$))"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zN0yZ0/1)

Comment: Maybe you should replace `\s` by `(\s|$)`.

Comment: Not matching words followed by spaces

Comment: make `[.,]` as optional.